# How to create a Kafka Topic using Confluent.Kafka .Net Client

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

It seems like most popular .net client for Kafka (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) is missing methods to setup and create Topics. 
When calling `Producer.ProduceAsync()` the topic is created automatically but I can't find a way to setup partitions, retention policy and other settings.

I tried to find any examples online but all I found just use defaults.

Maybe there is another .net client that I can use instead?

Comment: "ProduceAsync" only creates a topic automatically if  auto topic creation is enabled at the broker (which in most cases, it shouldn't be)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is now available in latest release of Confluent.Kafka .Net client library.

See: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/b7b04fed82762c67c2841d7481eae59dee3e4e20/examples/AdminClient/Program.cs

```
        using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers }).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                await adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] { 
                    new TopicSpecification { Name = topicName, ReplicationFactor = 1, NumPartitions = 1 } });
            }
            catch (CreateTopicsException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occured creating topic {e.Results[0].Topic}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Confluent yet not provide any APIs to create topic from dot net client, however there is a workaround for the same.

> 1. Set `auto.create.topics.enable = true` in kafka configuration
> 2. use `var brokerMetadata = producer.GetMetadata(false, topicName);` to query available topics in existing brokers, if specified topic is
>      not available then kafka will create a topic with specified name.

```
    private static bool CreateTopicIfNotExist(Producer producer, string topicName)
    {
        bool isTopicExist = producer.GetMetadata().Topics.Any(t => t.Topic == topicName);
        if (!isTopicExist)
        {
            //Creates topic if it is not exist; Only in case of auto.create.topics.enable = true is set into kafka configuration
            var topicMetadata = producer.GetMetadata(false, topicName).Topics.FirstOrDefault();
            if (topicMetadata != null && (topicMetadata.Error.Code != ErrorCode.UnknownTopicOrPart || topicMetadata.Error.Code == ErrorCode.Local_UnknownTopic))
                isTopicExist = true;
        }
        return isTopicExist;
    }
```

Thus you can use this work around, I know this is dirty solution but it seems there is no other way as of now.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is still exists: the topic will be created with all default settings. Simple call to `Producer.ProduceAsync()` also creates a topic if not exists

Comment: Answer needs to be updated with the correct api, or clarify this will use default topic settings

Answer (score 0):

`Confluent.Kafka.AdminClient` is available in version `1.0.0-experimental-2` but doesn't allow creating topics etc.

Its built on `librdkafka` [which doesn't have APIs for this yet](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ).

So for now you have to configure this on the broker using e.g. `bin\windows\kafka-topics.sh --create ...`