# How to modify in C # the time that Kafka keeps the messages of a topic?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I am looking for documentation about it and I see that there is a property called **retention** to determine the time that the messages of a topic are kept in Kafka. The problem is that I cannot find that property or any similar property to apply in C # code.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Google for `c# kafka specify retention`.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no C# property because these are strings in all clients except for the Java clients where there's enum values for client and topic configs

In the [AdminClient](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.IAdminClient.html) you can create topics with a second optional parameter that accepts an object containing the values you're interested in

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/861

[How to create a Kafka Topic using Confluent.Kafka .Net Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063406/how-to-create-a-kafka-topic-using-confluent-kafka-net-client)